# VM Windows Server 2022 does not start on its own after reboot

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machines, startup, windows-server-2022, reboot

I have a VM created in google cloud, where I use a Windows Server 2022 Datacenter, but every time I restart this machine through the remote connection through my windows 11, the VM does not start by itself (I need to access the remote connection again, so that windows starts), and I need it to restart every day and run an application that I use, would anyone know the reason for this?

Comment: Review the Windows Event Logs and the Google Cloud Compute Engine instance logs to determine why the VM did not start.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to check your cloud logging by following this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-reboots#gcloud) so that you can verify the issue you are having.

Might as well consider this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69208470/gcp-vm-instance-schedule-randomly-not-starting-vm) that might relate to your issue, which points on the high memory utilization of the VM due to unresponsive start.